# how to get images from firestore to gridview

Tags: flutter

am trying to fetch image from firestore to gridview.but to each container where image should be displayed am getting the error.....NoSuchMethodError: '[]',Dynamic call of null,Receiver:instanceof '_jsonQuerySnapshot', argument[0]..

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection("Products")
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder:
                                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                              return snapshot.data == null
                                  ? const Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                                  : GridView.builder(
                                      gridDelegate:
                                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                              crossAxisCount: 2),
                                      itemBuilder:
                                          (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                        DocumentSnapshot data =
                                            snapshot.data![index];
                                        Map getdoc =
                                            data.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                        return Container(
                                          height: height * 0.3,
                                          width: width * 0.3,
                                          child: Image.network(
                                              getdoc["product_image_url"]
                                                  [index]),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                                    );
                            }))
```

Comment: Could you please add a snapshot of your Firestore?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
child: Image.network(getdoc["product_image_url"]),
```

Comment: i have tried but same error